# How to edit .java source code of a module in Magnolia Community Edition?

Tags: java, web-applications, magnolia

I want to edit the Java source code of a Magnolia module (As an example: magnolia-imaging) and then compile it as a .jar.

I downloaded **Magnolia 6.0 Community Edition** bundle including Tomcat (*magnolia-community-demo-bundle*). I start the server and install the modules. When I look inside the (*magnolia-6.0\apache-tomcat-9.0.10\webapps\magnoliaAuthor*), It includes the .jar file of each module (*example: magnolia-imaging-3.4.2*) however I find no java files in the Magnolia project.

I also tried to get the Java source code by building the Archetype of Magnolia Community Edition, with a *Maven Clean Install*, using the *settings.xml* provided in the *Magnolia Nexus Repository* (*https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/#m2-settings-templates;magnolia-community-public*), however I still can't find any Java source code to edit.

I expect to be able to edit the Java files in my Eclipse IDE, after loading the project tree of a Magnolia modules with organized packages including the .Java files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest way is to fetch the module that you want to change from https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES and after making necessary changes built the jar out of it. After you need to drop the jar to magnoliaAuthor/libs folder. (Make sure you remove the older one.) and that should be all the necessary steps to achieve custom code.

Cheers,

Hope that helps,